# Writing a regex filter to parse a range of dates stored in reverse-timestamp order

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have to parse a range of row keys by date in Google Cloud BigTable using a regex filter, where each date in the rowkey is stored as a reverse-timestamp according to the Unix Epoch (00:00:00 on January 1st, 1970).

For example, given `Date d = "2018-03-09T10:48:00.000Z"`, this date in MS since the Unix Epoch is `d.valueOf() = 1520592480000`. In JavaScript, the maximum allowable integer is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991`, and so we calculate *d*'s reverse date *r* by taking the difference: `var r = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - d` where `r = 9005678662260991`.

Given two reverse dates *r1* and *r2*, how can I write a regular expression in RE2 to get all date strings within this range? I'm trying to find all dates within a range using reverse-timestamp rowkeys in BigTable using NodeJS (limited documentation), so if there are any easier solutions than this that you're aware of I'll also accept those!

Thanks

Comment: Extract the date strings and reverse the order so you don't have the overflow problem? regex might be leading you astray; I think you can do this without regex much more easily than with it.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for the Javascript maximum integer is making the lookup less natural and efficient.

I would suggest expressing the rows in a way that are easily understandable by both Javascript and Bigtable, while maintaining an natural order and properties for filtering.

If you need reversal to prevent hotspotting, you can try reversing only part of the timestamp (10's of seconds?) or adding a salt into the key (you can check the "Salting" section here https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series).

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to handle integer ranges using pure regular expressions, only character ranges: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861720/643848
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Moreover, Bigtable will be much more efficient if you can express your queries to take advantage of lexicographical row keys for filtering/scanning, i.e. if you can set up your schema such that you can express the range you want using a simpler query like a RowRange (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2#rowrange).

You may also want to consider just issuing a broader query and then doing more processing and filtering client-side.